# how to convert the ip address array in re.findall() response to string

Tags: python-2.7

I have this code and want to eventually convert the IP address in `re.findall()` response to a string. But I always get an error (see below).

```
url = 'http://checkip.dyndns.org'
request = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
ip = str(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', request))
print ip
```

I always get this error

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Can someone tell me what is the best way to convert it?
thank you.

Comment: Use a proper API that returns a structured result rather than arbitrary text and don't worry about it? E.g. https://api.ipify.org/?format=json

Comment: `print ip` works fine (it prints `['a.b.c.d']`, since you've converted list to string, but that's expected output), can you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: ``ip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', request)[0] `` works? .
``re.findall()`` returns a list of strings already if there are two or more elements then your ``string(blah blah)`` will fail, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is, that you are converting `re.findall()` into a string, but that function returns a list as was mentioned in the comments. So the best for you is to use `re.findall(...)[0]` if you expect only one result/one ip and if not, then print all results:

```
ips = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', request)
for ip in ips:
    print str(ip)
```

Personally, I think the best would be to print all things, or at least check for the length of `re.findall()`, because you can easily miss things this way. Also I'd like to recommend you [this](https://regex101.com/#python) site for regex debugging. :)

[image]